# What is the best and easy way to create sub domain in xampp

Tags: xampp

I want to create or add local subdomain like test.localhost.com,
can you help me.

i tried to add this domain to my windows host file

```
127.0.0.1 test.localhost.com
```

it show page not working, what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first i want to tell you that windows hosts file can only redirect you to specify IP address only but localhost.com is not open by default in xampp so you have to add localhost.com manually.

Go To `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` and paste this code at footer.

```
# FOR test 
NameVirtualHost test:80 
<VirtualHost *:80> 
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/test"> 
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes 
    AllowOverride All 
    Order deny,allow 
   allow from All 
</Directory> 
ServerName test 
ServerAlias www.test 
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test" 
</VirtualHost>
```

and Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and give direction for redirection using this code as you already done.
paste this code at bottom.

`127.0.0.1 test`